# Passing Special character with application/x-www-form-urlencoded Post Method in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append("UserName",UserName);
    urlSearchParams.append("Password",Password);
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    var header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    header.append("Accept", "application/json");
    let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, option)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

above is the method which i am using to pass the parameter to api.

Issue is when i pass the string `test@123` only test@1 is available in the API.
But when i pass 123456789 complete string available.

I am hoping for some help.

Comment: Can you suggest me alternative

Comment: you need to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape special chars. Otherwise send and receive json

Answer (score 2):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape special characters or reserved characters that may not go with URI Params.

```
let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append("UserName",encodeURIComponent(UserName));//here
    urlSearchParams.append("Password",encodeURIComponent(Password));//and here
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()

    var header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    header.append("Accept", "application/json");
    let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, body, option)
        .map(res => res.json());
```

Comment: Now it in the API level we are getting as test%40123 not as test@123

Comment: depending on server side technology you will have to decode it.. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent

Comment: var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://localhost:51106/api/AdminLogin",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "041d7e99-ac96-911b-d05b-708eb933746e"
  },
  "data": {
    "UserName": "admin",
    "Password": "test@123"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});

Comment: that code above work fine in postman i need similar one i don't want to modify the server side since it is working fine for ajax call and for other service call.

Comment: here you are not using `URLSearchParams`. Try setting properties in  a regular object and sending

Comment: Hi Suraj, I have observed that when i change urlSearchParam.append order that is urlSearchParam.append("Password") and then UrlSearchParam.append("UserName") it is working fine. Again if both parameter includes @ character in the string then second parameter getting the issue.

Comment: When i send it in regular object form at the API level  object coming as null.

Comment: yes.. Thats how URLSearchParams work .. It arranges data to be sent through the url where some characters are restricted https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: As I said.. either you have to decode at other end or change content type to "application/json" and receive json on server side

Comment: It is working fine after changing let body= {
            Password: Password,
            UserName: UserName
        }
        
        var header = new Headers();
        header.append("content-type", "application/json");
        //header.append("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        header.append("ContentType", "application/json");
        header.append("Accept", "application/json");
        let option = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });
        return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, JSON.stringify(body), option)
            .map(res => res.json());

Answer (score 2):

Use following Javascript function:

encodeURIComponent(value)

This will give you the encoded string

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and had to use:

`encodeURI(value)`

I tried `encodeURIComponent(value)` but it did not work in my case. Could be because the two functions handle some special characters differently.